# Is it possible to use a system of ring-shaped muscles to pump blood instead of a heart?

Tags: science-based, biology

Most species which use blood (that I know of) use a heart or set of hearts to pump their blood around their body. However, in something like our digestive system, a series of muscles are used to force digested food through tubes instead of a central pump.

My question is, would using a similar ringed muscle series instead of hearts for a species work for pumping blood, or would it be too inefficient to consider?

(for clarification, efficiency is in terms of energy required in proportion to blood successfully moved, and how easily the system could be stopped/interrupted)

Comment: Do you mean like each blood vessel working like a [linear peristaltic pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peristaltic_pump#/media/File:Schlauchpumpe-lineare-Verdraengung.png)? ([Full article on peristaltic pumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peristaltic_pump))

Comment: We humans use [peristalsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peristalsis) in (part of) the [lympatic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lymphatic_system). And anyway, the heart is actually made of "ring-shaped muscles".

Comment: Is the difference that you're hoping to get rid of valves? We have valves all through our venous system, so would any "tall" creature. You might get away with it with worms or suchlike. Can you be specific about the creature that you're designing, what've you got so-far?

Comment: @AngryMuppet no valves? has there been an edit? because I don't see anything in the question to imply that motivation?

Comment: I'm not clear what the OP wants. I know we need clarity for an answer to work. The basic difference between what the OP suggests about muscle contractions and already existing hearts is  - valves (and two such systems back-to-back in the case of the human heart) and centralisation. So, what does the OP mean? What kind of creature are they designing? @Pelinore

Comment: the heart IS a ring of muscle around a blood vessel.

Comment: I don't see that @AngryMuppet, the system the OP asks about doesn't preclude valves by its nature and in fact might work best with valves, so if anything I would have assumed the opposite of what I think you did? I would have assumed that valves were assumed to be included.

Comment: @Pelinore Let me make this absolutely crystal clear so there can be no misunderstanding, no mistaken apprehension about what I'm saying: I agree with you. - Basically I just want the OP to clarify what they've got in mind beyond the blood, i.e. context. A prod about valves might have made them think about that and clarify. Not happened yet obviously, but let's hope they come back before the internet gets old and senile.

Comment: @AngryMuppet fair enough, clarity is needed, but in saying what you have *"The basic difference between what the OP suggests about muscle contractions and already existing hearts is - valves"* you do appear to be putting words into the OPs mouth, it looks like you're saying that the OPs question specifically says that he wants no valves, and it doesn't .. that, to be *"crystal clear"* ;) is my issue with your comment, not that you're calling for clarity, which I agree with.

Comment: Are you looking for something analogous or different from earthworms, with 10 aortic arches instead of "hearts?"  https://sciencing.com/many-hearts-earthworm-have-4597386.html

Comment: I was trying for hyperbolic comedy, too late at night and too hot here for me to write goodly stuffs. @Pelinore

Comment: @AngryMuppet fair enough, my sense of humour may just be on bypass right now :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Earthworms:

I think you are looking for a circulatory system like the humble [earthworm](https://sciencetrends.com/how-many-hearts-does-a-worm-really-have/). The very unique structure of the earthworm heart means it lacks a singular heart, but instead has a series of aortic arches that squeeze the body and force the blood through a closed circulatory system. The earthworm also controls this set of "hearts" directly via nervous system like we do, rather than by a secondary set of muscular signals.

[image: earthworm]

The question is, what kind of organism do you want to run with this setup? There isn't a lot of information to say how the arrangement works in a larger organism. [Cockroaches](https://www.livescience.com/49795-strange-animal-hearts.html) have a slightly analogous system with 12-13 separate hearts (depending on your definitions) to allow much greater redundancy in a fairly sophisticated organism. The loss of function of part of the system still allows circulation to operate. The cockroach model is using an open circulatory system, so it doesn't match quite as well.

[image: cockroach]

Answer (score 19):

This is literally how the circulatory system of insects works: [fruit fly video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KY1wf6UXmjY)

Now the context is different from vertebrates: insects have an open, non-pressurised circulatory system, and the dorsal vessel (the peristaltic blood pump) is not even a closed tube, but partially open and sort of just helping the haemolymph slosh around more efficiently.

Whether this design would be sufficient in a closed circulatory system is perhaps debatable. But developmentally speaking, it’s pretty trivial: the heart is *already* basically a tube (well, a pair of tubes) knotted [around itself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0qyagIgBPw)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are organisms where blood is moved by muscular blood vessels that "contract in peristaltic waves" ([source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5378490/)). This is the known alternative to the chambered heart and is seen in some annelids.

The largest and most conspicuous vessel in the earthworm traverses the full length of the animal. It collects blood from other vessels and drives it forwards through contractile peristaltic waves that originate at the posterior end of the animal and move forward.

Peristaltic pumps lack coordination between the blood that is entering the contractile region and the blood that is leaving it. Despite some improvements to the peristaltic design, such as the evolution of one-way valves and coordination in contractions, the loss of energy associated with backflow, distension of wall segments ahead of the stream, and pump reversals constrain body size and metabolic activity. This promotes evolution of the true hearts

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying only on a single centralized heart pump to push blood around,
humans also have [skeletal-muscle pumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal-muscle_pump) sometimes called a ["second heart" in the muscles](https://veinatlanta.com/your-second-heart/) of the lower leg and foot.

When running, these muscles periodically squeeze and contract, not only moving the body, but also squeeze reservoir veins deep inside the muscle, periodically pushing blood out of the muscle and allowing it to flow back in.
Valves in those veins allow that blood to flow only in the correct direction (against gravity during the run).
Even when standing still, those same valves prevent blood from sinking under the influence of gravity, moving the wrong direction and pooling in the feet.